# How can I use integer field as a foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django

You can see my files below. I have two models: Order and OrderedBook. When a user makes an order, I create a few OrderedBook instances(its number depends on how many books the user ordered). In addition, OrderedBook has a field 'orderNumber' and it's a foreign key. However, I want it to be an integer, but Django requires an Order instance. How can I implement it?

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    orderNumber = models.AutoField('Номер замовлення', primary_key=True)
    userFirstName = models.CharField('Ім\'я', max_length=32)
    userLastName = models.CharField('Прізвище', max_length=32)
    userPatronymic = models.CharField('По-батькові', max_length=32)
    userEmail = models.EmailField('Електронна адреса', )
    userPhone = models.CharField('Номер телефону', max_length=13, validators=[phoneNationalFormatValidator, phoneLessNumbersValidator, phoneValidFormatValidator])
    delivery = models.CharField('Доставка', choices=DELIVERY, max_length=10, default='NovaPoshta')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default = timenow)
    deliveryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Замовлення №{self.orderNumber}"

class OrderedBook(models.Model):
    orderNumber = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=CASCADE, to_field='orderNumber')
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Замовлення №{self.orderNumber} - {self.book}'
```

**views.py**

```
def cart(request):
items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
total = sum(x.book.price for x in items)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        theSameForm = form.save()
        # after purchase delete all ordered books from user's cart and reduce their count by 1
        for cartItem in items:
            book = Book.objects.get(ISBN=cartItem.book.ISBN)
            book.number -= 1
            book.save()

            newOrderedBook = OrderedBook.objects.create(
                orderNumber = theSameForm.pk, # problem
                user = request.user,
                book = book,
            )

            cartItem.delete()

        return redirect('index')

    context = {
        'items': items,
        'total': total,
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)

form = OrderForm()
context = {
    'items': items,
    'total': total,
    'form': form
}

return render(request, 'cart.html', context)
```

**P.S.** As you can see, I set `to_field` parameter in OrderedBook orderNumber field. However, it still requires Order instance

Comment: what happens if you change that problem line to `orderNumber_id = theSameForm.pk` or `orderNumber = theSameForm`

Comment: oh, everything works. In addition give me a link to find out how '_id' works or explain it to me please :)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

Comment: is 'to_field' parameter necessary in this code?

Comment: it should default to the pk of the foreign table, so I'd guess not. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default You may also benefit from reading https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2018/02/10/django-tip-22-designing-better-models.html for the naming conventions (will save you headaches later)

Comment: Thanks you so much :). You can leave you answer and I'll set it as an answer